# JSON with PHP issue

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hello all just a bit stuck on this issue.

PHP5 is enabled. Just wondering on where I am going wrong, or the best way to detect an error. Here the first part, its the javascript code that works on a .html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var  obj1 = {name:"Wayne", age:32, location:"Ireland"};
var  obj2 = {name:"Robert", age:25, location:"Ireland"};
var  obj3 = {name:"Chris", age:26, location:"Jama"};

var  classC3 = {student1:obj1, student2:obj2, student:obj3};

document.write(obj1.name + "<br>");
document.write(classC3.student2.name + "<br>");
</script>
```

The next part is where I am trying to run it with .PHP in the filefile

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<?php
echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\">';
echo 'var  obj1 = {name:\"Wayne\", age:32, location:\"Ireland\"};';
echo 'var  obj2 = {name:\"Robert\", age:25, location:\"Ireland\"};';
echo 'var  obj3 = {name:\"Chris\", age:26, location:"Jama\"};';

echo 'var  classC3 = {student1:obj1, student2:obj2, student:obj3};';

echo 'document.write(obj1.name + \"<br>\");';
echo 'document.write(classC3.student2.name + \"<br>\");';
echo '</script>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea's?

Comment: Look at your page source -- it will tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Why put that inside PHP at all?  You are not dynamically injecting any PHP values into the javascript. Just because a file has `.php` extension doesn't mean it has to have any PHP in it.

Comment: You don't need to escape your double quotes because you use single quotes for the Strings, `'"'` or `"\""`.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you have double-quotes inside single-quotes, you don't have to escape them in PHP. By including them, you're creating invalid javascript. Remove the backslashes (or include one before Jama in obj3 and put all your PHP strings in double-quotes) and you should be okay.